# Can books be counted as books even if some points were used to cover points left in the hand and foot?

Tags: hand-and-foot

Say that partners meld and made one clean book (A's-140 points and one dirty book of 8's-80 points=220). The other team went out.  The partners had cards remaining from their hand plus those in their foot=300 points.   The points left in their hand and foot equaled more than the points left on the board.

Can they count the books as books (one clean and one dirty=800 points) even though they had to use some of the points from the books to cover the points left in their hand and foot?

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange! I made a few edits to make it clearer what you were asking and made the title more explicit. Since we have tags for each game, it isn't necessary to state the name in the title. If I misinterpreted your meaning, feel free to make further edits. I don't play this game myself, but based on the answers to other questions about Hand and Foot, I'm sure you'll get a great answer before too long!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your score at the end of a round is always

+ points made in books

+ points from cards played (including cards in completed books)

- points left in hand

You can count all 3 separately and then add them together if you want. You don't actually need to remove cards for the negatives, but most people find it easier to pair up cards for the second and third and cancel them out.